# Ignoring string in url .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

so I've this issue and to ask I'm not able to resolve it, is there someone that can help me?

I will explain my issue:

I have on my customer site some link with this format http://localhost/details/27949077/ and they should be for instance
http://localhost/Bournemouth/EastCliff/details/27949077/

// Dynamic

http://localhost/details/property_id
http://localhost/town/locality/details/property_id/

How can say to ignore the first and second string to apache with .htaccess? because Wordpress in showing 404 page

Thanks at all

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/details/(.+)$ index.php?pagename=details&property=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

Comment: I have resolve with that, maybe is useful for someone that is looking